# Autocomplete function with proprietary database

Tags: android, iphone, dictionary, autocomplete

We are building an app for Android and iPhone. In this app, we will like to use autocomplete feature to work with our own databases not OS/phone dictionary. Is it possible? how? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the complete system, you can use a SQLite DB on the phone having your words registered in it, and use queries on each letter the user enters to get the most relevant completing word

`(for example using "...LIKE word='"+EnterCaracts+"%')` .